# How to post a status on my facebook page? [ASP.NET MVC 4]

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-page

I want to post statuses on my facebook page via my web application. The web app is created with ASP.NET MVC 4 and c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/).

There you get access to a lot of documentation about how to interact with the Facebook API, how to authenticate with Facebook and so on.
In general you get almost everything you need to integrate the Facebook API into your application.